# Changing the order of Columns when page loads from desktop to mobile responsive layout

Tags: css, responsive-design

In the below given layout, 
When the width of page is lowered than 600px, I want to place **Column2** above **Column1**
I tried using `display: flex; flex-direction: column-reverse;` but it instead of reversing the order of column it reversed the content order of the column.

Here is snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    /**Uncommenting below will lead to content of column reversed and not the order of column reversed**/
    /*display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;*/
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Two Column Layout</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect (the columns will stack on top of each other instead of floating next to each other, when the screen is less than 600px wide).</p>
<div class="row" style="height: 20px; background-color: red;">
</div>
<div class="row" style="height: 20px; background-color: blue;">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
   <div class="cls1">
     <h2>Column 1</h2>
     <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cls2">
     <h2>Column 1.2</h2>
     <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cls3">
     <h2>Column 1.3</h2>
     <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried adding `display:flex` to the column - which made the column a `flex container` and elements inside of it his `flex items`. That's why you were reversing content inside the columns and not the columns themselves. You want to instead control columns inside the row. To do that, you need to make the row your `flex container` (apply `display:flex` to the row instead of the column). Here is a working CSS for your case:

```
.row {
  display: flex;  // makes the row a flex container
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}

.column {
  flex-grow: 1;  // makes all columns fill the width of the row equally
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Happy coding! Also in general you might avoid `floats` and use `flexbox` instead where possible. You can achieve the same but in a less complicated way in most cases ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct implementation with working example based on Accepted answer of @ajobi:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

.row {
  display: flex;  // makes the row a flex container
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .column {
    width: 100%;
    /**Uncommenting below will lead to content of column reversed and not the order of column reversed**/
    /*display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;*/
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Two Column Layout</h2>
<p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect (the columns will stack on top of each other instead of floating next to each other, when the screen is less than 600px wide).</p>
<div class="row" style="height: 20px; background-color: red;">
</div>
<div class="row" style="height: 20px; background-color: blue;">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
   <div class="cls1">
     <h2>Column 1</h2>
     <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cls2">
     <h2>Column 1.2</h2>
     <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="cls3">
     <h2>Column 1.3</h2>
     <p>Some text..</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```